# Why typescript treat it as never

Tags: typescript

I have some classes defined as follow:

```js
abstract class HttpError extends Error {
  abstract getHttpCode(): number;
}

class OkHttpError extends HttpError {
  getHttpCode(): number { return 200; }
}

class NotFoundHttpError extends HttpError {
  getHttpCode(): number { return 404; }
}

class DomainError extends Error { }
class CommandNotFound extends DomainError { }
```

I wrote the function that maps my `DomainError`s to `HttpError`s. The problem is that when I am using `isCommandNotFound` instead of `error instanceof CommandNotFound` typescript screaming that the `error` in the last line has type `never`. I do not understand why. Can someone explain it to me? Mapping functions and type guard definition below:

```js
const mapDomainToHttpError = (error: DomainError): HttpError => {
    if (isCommandNotFound(error)) {
        return new NotFoundHttpError(error.message);
    }
    
    return new OkHttpError(error.message);
}
```

```js
const mapDomainToHttpError = (error: DomainError): HttpError => {
    if (error instanceof CommandNotFound) {
        return new NotFoundHttpError(error.message);
    }
    
    return new OkHttpError(error.message);
}
```

```js
const isCommandNotFound = (subject: Error): subject is CommandNotFound => subject instanceof CommandNotFound
```

Comment: it seems you have found one more TS bug))

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's because Typescript has a structural type system, not a nominal type system.